# "The term '/node.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program"

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

I'm attempting to make a CLI with Node.js following the tutorial on [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-to-build-a-cli-with-node-js) and after doing `npm link` I get this error when using the command. I read an old overflow post which said to add node to my environment variables, which I have.

Here's the error:

```
& : The term '/node.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\thedi\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-project.ps1:15 char:5
+   & "/node$exe"  "$basedir/node_modules/@thedigs/create-project/bin/c ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (/node.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

And here's my current code:

```js
// bin/create-project

#!/usr/bin/env/node

require = require('esm')(module /*, options */);
require('../src/cli').cli(process.argv);
```

```js
// src/cli.js

export function cli(args) {
    console.log(args);
}
```

```json
// package.json

{
    "name": "@thedigs/create-project",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "A CLI to bootstrap my new projects, whatever that means.",
    "main": "src/index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon ."
    },
    "publishConfig": {
        "access": "public"
    },
    "bin": {
        "@thedigs/create-project": "bin/create-project",
        "create-project": "bin/create-project"
    },
    "keywords": [
        "cli",
        "create-project"
    ],
    "author": "thedigs",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^14.14.31",
        "esm": "^3.2.25",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
    }
}
```

My best guess is the tutorial is behind versions, hopefully one of you can sort this out for me. Thanks!

[Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwTfg.png)

Comment: Solutions go in the space below as an answer. Do not edit the question to add the solution.

Comment: I'm having the same issue

Comment: I have realized what we did wrong after comparison with my code. Add my answer is correct answer after checking it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for the answer but after comparing this code and my code suddenly realized that the path `#!/usr/bin/env/node` given to `bin/create-project` is completely wrong.

In my case, I have given it as `#! /user/bin/env node` but it has to be `usr` instead of using `user`.

In this case, it has to be...

> File: bin/create-project

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

require = require('esm')(module /*, options */);
require('../src/cli').cli(process.argv);
```

> Those spaces are a must when it comes to path.

Answer (score 0):

For reference: first line is a so-called [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

And why to use `env` here and not call `node` directly, is [summarized here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/566019) in another SE post.

Short: `env` acts as a proxy to find your desired interpreter, in your case `node` on the target system, even if it is maybe found in the users `~` home dir or something...